# MySQL block read or write access to one process in each row of a table

Tags: mysql, locking

we have a MySQL database with a table that has the following format:

account - quantity

There's one row per account and they can't be repeated.

We have multiple processes that can access and read each row, and each time a process accesses, quantity gets a +1.

So, if process1 access the table for account1 and quantity was 0, then quantity gets updated to 1.

But if two processes enter at the same time asking for the same account, and quantity is 2, the first one should update to 3 and the second one to 4.

This is extremely important as we can't lose or repeat any number in the sequence.

Is there any way to "lock" read or write access to a row in a table, so if two processes ask for the same row, the second one has to wait for the row to be "unlocked" to get an answer? we wouldn't want to lock the entire table, that would punish the performance a lot since just one row needs to be locked.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes! SELECT FOR UPDATE should work.
Thanks!